# CSS Gradient link text jumps on hover

Tags: css, hover, gradient

I am using gradient text color for my links on hover, however a strange jump effect is occurring ever since I added the css class. Whenever I hover the link it jumps like 2px-4px up.

When I remove the gradient color class all is normal again. Is there any fix to this? The custom code I added:

```
.bg-gradient-ligth {
  background-color: $white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, $white 0%, $ligth-grey 74%);
}

a {
  color:$green
}

a:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($gradient1, $gradient2);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.heading-gradient {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($gradient1, $gradient2);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

The rest is just plain Bootstrap and theme CSS. Which worked fine before. By the way it also cuts off the text of a gradient h1 title at the bottom.

Comment: Could you leave your full code to test the error?

Comment: I added the full code now, the rest is just plain Bootstrap and theme code. Which worked perfectly fine.

Comment: What browser.  I am not having this issue in Chrome or Safari: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/9d0ghsum/